# Facebook Pixel Warning: Multiple pixels with conflicting versions were detected on this page

Tags: facebook

I have 4 FB pixel on my page and it is showing "Facebook Pixel Warning: Multiple pixels with conflicting versions were detected on this page" warning.

I am getting following error:

Facebook Pixel Warning: Multiple pixels with conflicting versions were detected on this page
Facebook Pixel Warning: Multiple different pixels were detected on this page

How can i get rid of it? Does it stop firing and tracking pixels?

```
<!-- Facebook Conversion Code -->
<script>(function() {
var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
if (!_fbq.loaded) {
var fbds = document.createElement('script');
fbds.async = true;
fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
_fbq.loaded = true;
}
})();
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
window._fbq.push(['track', 'XXXXXXXXXXX', {'value':'0.00','currency':'USD'}]);
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?ev=XXXXXXXXXXX&amp;cd[value]=0.00&amp;cd[currency]=USD&amp;noscript=1" /></noscript>
<!-- Facebook Conversion Code -->

<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', 'XXXXXXXXXXX');
fbq('track', "PageView");</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=XXXXXXXXXXX&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->

<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', 'XXXXXXXXXXX');
fbq('track', "PageView");
window._fbq.push(['track', 'Lead']);
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=XXXXXXXXXXX&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->

<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', 'XXXXXXXXXXX');
fbq('track', "PageView");</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=XXXXXXXXXXX&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Comment: I don't want to see warning. I want to remove it. Is there better way to do it? Does it stopping tracking?

Comment: As the message says, you are using different versions of the pixel embed code. You should change this, so that all of them are using the latest version.

Comment: You need to change your site to 1x1 resolution.  Worked for me, error's gone.